# PHP response true / false and correct IF statemen

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

In add to cart function can be placed discount, discounts are made via xxx-hashid. i figure out that problem is when user want cheat and type random xxx-123456 my system crash.

hashid is from Ivan Akimov.

is possible to achiev, when hashID (userID) doesnt exist function return code isnt valid but without crash ?

```
public function getIdByHash($hashid) {
    $response = ['valid' => false];
    if ($hashid){
        $response['valid'] = true;
        $hashid = explode("PMX-",$hashid)[1];
        $hashids = new Hashids("",6);  
    return $hashids->decode($hashid)[0];
    } 
        if ($hashid){
            $response ['valid'] = false;
        return $hashids = "PMX-"."dGRLrb";
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide which `xxx-hashid` is crashig

Comment: @kamlesh Paul for example PMX-123456

Comment: PMX-dGRLrb is valid code but with 0% discount, it was my idea, but i may be wrong

Comment: The second `if ($hashid) { ... }` is completely pointless and will never evaluate as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try :

```php
public function getIdByHash($hashid) {
    $response = ['valid' => false];
    if ($hashid){
        $response['valid'] = true;
        try {
            $hashid = explode("PMX-",$hashid)[1];
            $hashids = new Hashids("",6);  
            return $hashids->decode($hashid)[0];
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $response ['valid'] = false;
        }
    } 
    return $hashids = "PMX-"."dGRLrb";

}
```

Comment: The second if-statement is completely pointless and will never evaluate as true.

Comment: Yes that's right, and even if it was evaluated, it would alway return true because it's a variable assignment

Comment: How is `if ($hashid)` a variable assignment? The second if is pointless because it's identical to the first if-statement, which will always call `return`. So the only time the second if-statement will be executed is if `$hashid` is falsy.

Comment: I'm talking about return $hashids = "PMX-"."dGRLrb";

Comment: That's not an if-statement. It's also not using the same variable. But yes, it's also pointless.

Comment: That's exactly why I said "if it was evalutated", then the return would be useless anyway